# How to run an asyncio method from synchronous and asynchronous methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, python-decorators

In my project, I have a decorator to call coroutines in **synchronous** methods:

```
def async_test(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        coro = asyncio.coroutine(f)
        future = coro(*args, **kwargs)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(future)
    return wrapper


 @async_test
    async def test_foo(self):
        # test stuff
```

I need this decorator to run the tests directly from my IDE.

But now, I need to call them from an **asynchronous** method (after an `await`) and I am having `RuntimeError`:

> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

How can I solve this problem with the asyncio loop?

Comment: Can you show how you're calling the async method?

Comment: Your approach won't work because asyncio event loop isn't reentrant. You should have **separate** synchronous entry points to async functionality, and use `await` to invoke async functions from other async functions.

Comment: Maybe I should find a way to bypass this decorator

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem bypassing the decorator. Now, when I am in an asynchronous function, I just need to do `await test_foo.bypass()`

```
def async_test(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        coro = asyncio.coroutine(f)
        future = coro(*args, **kwargs)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(future)

    wrapper.bypass = f
    return wrapper
```